# Pandas AssertionError: Must be mixed type DataFrame

Tags: csv, import, pandas

I'm still having issues with Pandas importing data and it has been giving me headaches.  I have some previous posts.  Anyway my lastest attempt at a simple CSV file resulted in an "AssertionError: Must be mixed type DataFrame" in frame.py.  In that example I could import a CSV file I made if I only imported columns that were integers. 
Now that got me wondering if something else may be wrong.  So I went back to basics and tried an example from Pandas.  Using data

```
    date,A,B,C
20090101,a,1,2
20090102,b,3,4
20090103,c,4,5
```

I then tried to

```
pd.read_csv('foo.csv')
```

and it still gave this error.  I have searched for other instances of others with this error but couldn't find anything.  I'm wondering if it is something on my system. Running windows64, EPD (with pandas-0.10.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe installed), Wing IDE editor (v4.1.9-1).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This should work without error (and does on my pandas 0.10.1). It *could* be something with your system/EPD... it *may* be worth installing via [pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)? :S Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: what do you get if you run `pandas.__version__` in the same process you're trying to read the file from?

Comment: Thanks all.  It turned out that I had a simple line of "print DF" which was causing the error not the "pd.read_csv".  I think that error has to do with the way in which Wing IDE can display the DF and has nothing to do with Pandas

Answer (score 0):

From Wing tech support:

"Wing is stopping at the failed assert because its default configuration
is to stop when any AssertionError is raised; this can be changed by
removing AssertionError from the list of Always Report exceptions in the
Debugger -> Exceptions preferences"

Answer (score 0):

I also get this assertion in Wing.

There is a check box on the upper left corner of the "Exceptions" tab in Wing labeled "Ignore this exception location", I checked that off and Wing stopped bugging me about it.